Need Guidance on a DIY crane project
I'm working on a DIY project and am in need of a little guidance with my circuit setup.  Here is the setup:
Motor:  12V, 0.6A, 10W (max output), Load current: 0.6A, Stall: 1.65A,
Potentiometer/Switch: 6V-28V, 3A, 80W (max output),
Wire:  20AWG
I was planning on bridging (4) 9V batteries to create 36V of power, but then saw a Youtube video that suggested to use a variable adapter if power needs were too high for batteries.  I have no electrical background.
I'd like to use a variable universal adapter:  3V-12V, 12W, 1A output, but not sure how the pot works in Current calculation of a series circuit.

You shouldn't need a variable voltage source and a control potentiometer; just one, probably the pot since it seems like the one you have is more suited to your application. 9V batteries are unsuitable for this application, so a wall-powered AC/DC supply is appropriate. Please link datasheets for the pot, universal adapter, and motor if you have them.

Voltage used relates to the motor voltage and the switch voltage is simply a maximum rating it can handle. 9 volt transistor batteries not suitable for the task. You need a about 12 volt power supply that can provide the current required. Your variable controller should be adequate links to actual products used would be immensely useful.

If your motor is 12V, why would you want to "bridge" them for 36V? Also, I'm almost certain you will burn your potentiometer out (even if you did have the correct voltage setup).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you all for kindly taking the time to respond!  Issue:  What power supply is needed to work with the Switch & Potentiometer to power the motor listed below.  Here are links to the components being used or being considered:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C7GP9FYS?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071H2YQG5?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B015PXUHYA/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2OLXLZMA0RX9P&psc=1


I'd like to use a variable universal adapter: 3V-12V, 12W, 1A output, but not sure how the pot works in Current calculation of a series circuit.

It's generally not a pot in there but actually a multi-position switch.
These variable supplies can be interesting when overloaded (1.6A stall current will overload a 1A supply)  sometimes the supply will respond by reducing the voltage until it can provide enough current, in a motor with will cause slow starting.  sometimes the supply will respond by shutting down. A motor will twitch then stop.
Using a 2A supply will be more reliable.
